# Functions whose limit at infinity is zero are closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F=\{f\in C(R):\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0\}$, show $F$ is closed in $C(R)$.

First of all a little side question, why does the question specifically say that $F$ is closed in $C(R)$? Any limit point of $F$ will necessarily be a continuous function, right? This little thing makes me confused about definition of closedness in subspace, since $C(R)$ is a subset of all functions from $R$ to $R$. Is $F$ still closed in the space of all functions from $R$ to $R$?

My attempt:

Let $d$ be the supremum metric. Let $g\in\overline{F}$. Then $\exists \{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ such that $f_n\to g$ uniformly.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists n_1\in N$ such that $\forall n\geq n_1, d(f_n,g)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Since $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ Cauchy, $\exists n_2\in N, \forall n\geq n_2, d(f_n,f_{n_2})<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

$\exists t>0,\forall |x|\geq t,|f_{n_2}(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Then $\forall n\geq n_2,\forall|x|\geq t,|f_n(x)|\leq |f_{n_2}(x)|+|f_{n_2}(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$

Then $\forall n\geq \max\{n_1,n_2\},\forall|x|\geq t,|g(x)|\leq|f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$.

Thus $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}g(x)=0$. Thus $g\in F$.

Am I correct?

Comment: What is your definition of $C(R)$?.

Comment: Continuous functions from R to R

Comment: $d$ is not defined in $C(R)$. Continuous functions need not be bounded.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Usually d is defined by $d(f,g)=max|f-g|$.  However $C(R)$ is not a complete metric space, si it is possible to have a limit which is not continuous.  Also the set F in the question has the same problem.

Comment: @herb steinberg I just checked my professor's notation. You are right C(R) means continuous and bounded. But can you explain why d is not defined on continuous but not bounded functions and what do you mean by it can have a limit that's not continuous

Comment: @Fluffy Skye If the function is not bounded, then its norm will be infinite, so it will be excluded.  Example of discontinuous limit: $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$, $f_n(x)=1$ for $x\gt \frac{1}{n}$  Connect pieces by $f_n(x)=nx$. for $0\le x\le \frac{1}{n}$.  Limit has discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: @herb steinberg Ok I'm more confused. Your example is a sequence of continuous and bounded functions right? Isn't the space of continuous and bounded functions complete?

Comment: I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137175/is-c-mathbb-r-complete

Comment: Another possible approach (though I know you asked for proof verification, hence comment not answer): we'll show the complement of $F$ is open.  So, suppose $f \notin F$.  That implies there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $R$, there exists $x$ with $|x| > R$ and $|f(x)| \ge \epsilon$.  Now show that for such an $\epsilon$, $B_\epsilon(f)$ is disjoint from $F$.

Comment: @Fluffy Skye
 The space of bounded functions is complete, but it is possible for a sequence of continuous functions to have a discontinuous limit.

Comment: @herb steinberg but your example above is not a valid example since your sequence doesn't converge under the supremum norm

Comment: @Daniel Schepler I would like to see different approaches. In fact I wanted to show the complement is open in the first place but I didn't know how to do that. Can you write an answer?

Comment: @Fluffy Skye  you are right.  In my mind I was confusing pointwise convergence with norm convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your side question: the question could easily have gotten away with not saying "in $C(\Bbb{R})$"; saying the set is closed would have implicitly meant inside the only metric space under consideration. But, sets are only "closed" or not with respect to topologies on the various spaces containing them. For example, $(0, 1]$ is closed in $(0, \infty)$, but not in $\Bbb{R}$, so if both spaces were under consideration, it'd be important to specify which.

As for your proof, it seems overly-complicated, but it appears correct. I do think it would benefit from a more direct approach. For example, it shouldn't be necessary to use Cauchiness and convergence. This is redundant; convergence should give you everything you need.

Following your basic outline,

> Suppose $g = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$, where $f_n \in F$. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. We wish to find $t$ such that
>   $$|x| \ge t \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
>   Since $f_n \to g$, there exists some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
>   $$d(f_n, g) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \implies \forall x \in \Bbb{R}, \, |f_n(x) - g(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
>   Since $f_n \in S$, there exists some $t$ such that
>   $$|x| \ge t \implies |f_n(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
>   Therefore,
>   $$|x| \ge t \implies |g(x)| \le |g(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)| < \varepsilon,$$
>   as required.

Comment: Ah yes you're right! I didn't get my head around the middle part so I redundantly used Cauchy.

Comment: Well, if C(R) isn't specified. Another possible space can be the space of real functions on R. Denote that space as T. Since C(R) is closed in T. F is closed in C(R) would also mean F is closed in T right?

Comment: The space of all functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$? Which norm would you put on that?

Comment: Can we still use the supremum norm?

Comment: Not really. Norms are not traditionally allowed to be infinite, but it would be for every unbounded function.

Comment: You could consider $F$ as a subset of the space of all bounded functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and while this is a sensible normed linear space, you also should ask the question, "why would you?". There's only one space relevant in the question, so it's perfectly reasonable to assume that's the space with respect to which $F$ is closed.

Comment: Ah thank you! That is what I have in mind.

Comment: Another question arising from the comment section. Do you understand C(R) as continuous and bounded or just continuous? If it is not bounded, then the metric is not well defined. But still every cauchy sequence would converge, right? So does it matter?

Comment: @FluffySkye It would have to be continuous and bounded, in order for it to be a normed linear space. I'm most used to seeing $C(X)$ in the context of $X$ being compact and Hausdorff, so I don't really know what the convention would be. In terms of whether the metric being infinite "matters" or not, I'm actually not really sure what kind of structure you lose or keep, but beware that such spaces are not metric spaces or normed linear spaces, so you cannot assume every theorem works!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to approach the problem seems to be to prove that a function $f \in C(\Bbb R)$ that's outside $F$ has a neighborhood that's also outside $F$.

If $f \notin F$, then $\exists y \gt 0 \ \text{such that} \ \forall  x \exists x_1 \gt x \ \text{with} \ \vert f(x_1) \vert \gt y$.  Thus, if $d(f, g) \lt y/2$, then $g \notin F$ (because $\forall  x \exists x_1 \gt x \ \text{with} \ \vert g(x_1) \vert \gt y/2$).  In other words, $B(f, y/2) \cap F = \emptyset$.  Since we chose an arbitrary $f \notin F$ and found a neighborhood outside $F$, the complement of $F$ is open so $F$ is closed.